# Extracing text from the middle of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a document that looks like the following:

```
{{ link.description | default text }}
{{ link.description |default text}}
```

As you can see, it might or might not have spaces around "default text". I want to extract the text "default text" using python's re library with this code:

```
default = re.findall('|[ ]*(.*?)[ ]*}}', doc)
```

Unfortunately, I do not get the desired results with the above regular expression. I am trying to capture "default text" using (.*?), but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: FYI: You can write `\s*` or just ` *` (space asterisk, it's not formatted properly) instead of `[ ]*`. A character group with just one character is kind of pointless.

Comment: from re import nothing; s.partition("|")[-1].rstrip('}').strip()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> st = '{{ link.description | default text }}'
>>> re.findall(r'\|\s*(.*?)\s*}',st)
['default text']
>>> st1  = '{{ link.description | default text }}'
>>> re.findall(r'\|\s*(.*?)\s*}',st1)
['default text']
>>>
```

In your regex `|[ ]*(.*?)[ ]*}}`.

1) You need to escape `|`.

2) Use `\s*` for `white-space` occurence.

Comment: Actually, `\s*` is needed here. Also, no laziness is needed for the `\s*` parts.

Comment: Initially I thought there will be `0 or 1` occurenece of white-space.

Comment: In that case it would be `\s?`

Comment: @NiklasB. Working on a small project so `+` is in my habit. So that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the | symbol since that has special meaning in a regex (it denotes alternate matches):

```
default = re.findall('\|[ ]*(.*?)[ ]*}}', doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't use regexes for something this simple.

```
ldescrs = open(fname,"r")
for ln in ldescrs.readlines():
   print ln.rstrip("{}\n").partition("|")[2].strip()
```

`ln.strip("{}\n ")` clears away the newline that is attached to each line in the file, and any spaces or braces

`.partition("|")[2]`
The resulting string is broken up at the `|` and we get element 2 which is the default text.

`.strip()` Since there could be spaces on the left or right of the default text, we throw those away too. Technically, we only need to left strip this, but it is one less thing to change if you decide you want to break out the link descr keyword which is element 0 of the partition results. That one might have extra space on the right.

You have a whole toolbox there, why reach for the jackhammer when a screwdriver with the right bit will do the job?